# Replace a character with a line break when a line break is required in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have strings (mostly place names) which I would like to specify where a line break should be, if a line break is required in the HTML.  I know how to deal with the space preference, but I'm stuck on the case of, for example, "Minneapolis/St. Paul".  Ideally, if forced to do a line break, you would like to replace the slash with a line break, rather than simply break the line there and leave the slash at the end of the first or beginning of the second line.

So on a single line you get `Minneapolis/St. Paul`, and when a line break is required, you would get `Minneapolis` on the first line and `St. Paul` on the second with no slash.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript might be what you want here. You could set an id on your text element e.g.

```html
<p id="text">My text/New line</p>
```

and then add a script tag afterwards:

```js
<script>
const element = document.querySelector('#text');
if (element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\//g, '<br />');
}
</script>
```

**Example**

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#text');
if (element) {
 element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\//g, '<br />');
}
```

```css
""
```

```html
<p id="text">My text/New line/yes!</p>
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for,  I want a solution which is responsive to the space available.